# Lombok - @Singular annotation not found

Tags: android, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am using Lombok for one of my apps.

I have a class declared with the annotation `@Builder`. The fields are annotated with `@SerializedName("xxxxx")` in order to support Gson.

However, one of the fields is a `List` so I would like to use the `@Singular` annotation for them, but looks like the lib doesn't know about this annotation.

```
@Builder 
public class ProductForm {
   @SerializedName("title") private String title;
   @SerializedName("description") private String description;
   @SerializedName("images") private List<ImageForm> imageFormList;
   @SerializedName("active") private boolean active;
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Doc [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html)

Comment: In order to get some help, please post the complete problematic code (i.e. with imports), version of lombok used, and the error message (compile time errror?).

Comment: Sorry my fault. The problem was the outdated version of the lib. I updated the dependency in gradle and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lombok 1.16.4 and your code (used `@lombok.Builder` not the deprecated one) I've no compile error when adding `@lombok.Singular` to `imageFormList` in your code.

So you probably forgot to import `@lombok.Singular` or used an old version of lombok.